# Provide Ad ids from server

Tags: android, firebase, admob, ads

I have one Android app with the admob ads ids hardcoded on it and now i need to change from admob account so, ads ids too and i want to minimize losses.

Is it right to set the ad units from server, like firebase for example? is this legal for admob-adsense?

Maybe i need mediation, but i dont want to depend on external companys.

So my plan is: update the app with ids on firebase. (setting my actual admob ids on firebase), then wait to have a good % of users on the new version and then change the ads ids on firebase for the new ids from the other account.

Best way to prevent this?

Thank you.

Comment: why not going with your first option simply save your ids on serve side that way you can change them how ever you like. you need to be aware of server loads when doing so if you have lots of users